# Method return values and exceptions

Tags: php, oop, exception, return-value

I have an interface called `iIncident` which defines a single method `when()`. `when()` should return a `DateTime` object.  I'm trying to decide what to do if `$object->when()` has no `DateTime` to return as might be the case just after an object is instantiated and before all its properties are set.

My choices are:

1. return false
2. throw some kind of `Exception`
3. return some default `DateTime` like '9999-01-01'

My inclination is to go with an `Exception` since `$object` really can't act as an incident until it knows when it occurred. I don't want to return a default `DateTime` because it complicates comparisons and it's not true. And I don't really want to return false because then I have to check for it every time I call the method- but if that is the preferred method, I guess I will.

Is throwing an exception the best way? And is there a predefined exception type I should use (none of the SPL ones struck me as particularly appropriate- but that might just indicate my lack of experience)?

Comment: You should trust yourself more.

Comment: If you call the `when()` method and the object isn't available yet, what would you want to do?  Stop execution, try again, move on?

Comment: @Surreal Dreams: if `when()` fails the block in which it is called would exit.  I'm figuring on using this for creating dependent sequential objects.  Something along the lines of: happening2 can't be saved until and unless a valid happening1 exists and has a date earlier than happening2's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're allowing an object to be created in an inconsistent state. If the object should be able to create date values, then it should receive all the dependencies it needs to do so in its constructor instead of through properties. If this is not possible, then you should consider trying to encapsulate the construction process through a factory (or factory method).

Answer (score 2):

Return `null` instead of `false`. That's the most common and natural way. And yes, you'll have to check  returned value every time.

#### Edit:

You could throw an exception but only if `when()` method cannot return `DateTime` due to some error or something.

Comment: +1 I agree with `null`. It's the natural way in most languages (e.g.: C++). Exceptions should be thrown only when an error prevents the workflow from continuing as expected.

Comment: Uncle Bob in his book "Clean Code" has a whole chapter against returning `null`. Instead he recommends to return a _default value_. The problem with `null` is that every receiver needs a `null` check.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are for errors on the part of the application or the server in my opinion.  There's no point in returning a bogus date, and if you return false, it has to be checked every time.

The solution is to extend `DateTime` and create a [*Special Case* (496)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html), possibly called `DateTimeNone`.

**Edit**: changed answer to *just* special case

Comment: Martin Fowler is awesome.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of returning false my self.  It makes logical sense to me in an 'if' condition to simply state `if($object->when() && $object->when()->before($otherdate))` etc, rather than returning a default date (like 12/31/1969, where that is a valid date).

Comment: I do too. Returning False or Null seems to me the best way to make me understand that the function had some problems. Actually probably Null is even better, but i did used false for a while and i didn't had any troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions are for exceptional conditions. Trying to read from / act on a partially constructed object is fairly exceptional.

Does the code path make any sense at all if there is no timestamp available? Probably not?

Throw (and catch, as appropriate) an exception.

Comment: I'll argue for throwing an exception and not returning false. False is a different type so you end up having to check for a different type instead of just expecting it to work. Also the code path is important as mentioned, if it doesn't make sense to check for a false value then an exception is the way to go. This posted while I wrote this so adding here instead of answer.

Comment: @Viper_Sb: this is my objection to `false` as well.

Comment: I'm using this to process complex forms.  So I create uninitialized objects and then set their properties with the $_POSTed values (filtered and validated, of course). Then I save the objects' information to the db if it conforms to the business rules regarding their relationships.